# 2. Differential equation with initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does my work look correct?

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-3(y-1)$ with $y(2)=-3$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-3(y-1)$$
$$\frac{1}{y-1}dy=-3dt$$
$$\int\frac{1}{y-1}dy=\int-3dt$$
$$\ln|y-1|=-3t+C$$
$$\ln|y-1|=C-3t$$
$$C=\ln|y-1|+3t$$

Using the condition $y(2)=-3$ and solving for C:
$$y(2)=-3$$
$$C=\ln|y-1|+3t$$
$$C=\ln|-3-1|+3(2)$$
$$C=\ln|-4|+6$$
$$C=\ln|4|+6$$
$$C=\ln(4)+6$$
$$C=1.3862+6$$
$$C=7.3862$$

Solving for y:
$$\ln|y-1|=C-3t$$
$$e^{\ln|y-1|}=e^{C-3t}$$
$$|y-1|=\frac{e^{C}}{e^{3t}}$$

Substitutin in $C=\ln(4)+6$:
$$|y-1|=\frac{e^{C}}{e^{3t}}$$
$$|y-1|=\frac{e^{\ln(4)+6}}{e^{3t}}$$
$$|y-1|=\frac{e^{\ln(4)}e^{6}}{e^{3t}}$$
$$|y-1|=\frac{4e^{6}}{e^{3t}}$$

Then we have for $y≥1$:
$$|y-1|=\frac{4e^{6}}{e^{3t}}$$
$$y-1=\frac{4e^{6}}{e^{3t}}$$
$$y=\frac{4e^{6}}{e^{3t}}+1$$

And for $y<1$:
$$|y|+1=\frac{4e^{6}}{e^{3t}}$$
$$|y|=\frac{4e^{6}}{e^{3t}}-1$$

Comment: I see one mistake in your fourth line. Be careful how you integrate 1/(y-1) with respect to y.
Also, try plugging in your initial value at (2,3). Does it work out? 
Finally, notice that you're taking the natural log of a negative number. Unless you're working in the complex plane (I suspect you're not), then such a term is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I can already see one mistake in that
$$\ln|y-1|=\int(y-1)^{-1}\;dy\neq-\ln(y-1).$$

Also, you ought to note in the derivation of this technique in solving separable ODE (i.e. an application of the chain rule) that you can incorporate the initial conditions in the integration, avoiding arbitrary constants and making more concrete that you are solving an IVP.

In particular we have for this IVP,

$$\int_{-3}^{y}(z-1)^{-1}\;dz=\int_{2}^{t}-3\;du$$
$$\ln|y-1|-\ln|-4|=-3t+6$$
$$y-1=e^{-3t+6+\ln 4}.$$

Therefore (after factoring the exponential and noting $e^{\ln 4}=4$),
$$y=y(t)=1+4e^{6-3t}.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the fourth equation.
$$
\int\frac{dy}{y-1}=\ln(y-1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

~ SPOILER ALERT: Here's the solution. ~

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-3(y-1)$ with $y(2)=-3$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-3(y-1)$$
$$\frac{1}{y-1}dy=-3dt, where \space y≠1$$
$$\int\frac{1}{y-1}dy=\int-3dt$$

$$ln|y-1|=-3t+C$$
$$e^{ln|y-1|}=e^{-3t+C}$$
$$|y-1|=C*e^{-3t}$$
$$y-1=C*e^{-3t}$$
Note: I removed the absolute value sign because either case (i.e., |y-1| = y-1 and |y-1| = 1-y) will get us the same end result; you could verify this yourself.

$$y=C*e^{-3t}+1$$

Now use your initial value: 
$y=C*e^{-3t}+1$, where $y(2)=-3$

$$-3=C*e^{-3(2)}+1$$
$$-3=C*e^{-6}+1$$
$$-4=C*e^{-6}$$

Thus, $C = -4e^6$. Plug that into your initial $y(t)$ and you should get:

$$y=-4e^{6-3t}+1.$$

Comment: $\int(y-1)^{-1}\;dy\neq\ln(y-1)$ without further specifying $y$.  Note that with $y=-3$ we get $\ln(-4)$ which is undefined.

Comment: @TaylorMartin I mistakenly put in parenthesis instead of absolute value signs, which I believe is the correct solution. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but why does $e^{ln|y−1|}=e^{−3t+C}$ become $|y−1|=C∗e−3t$, do we not need to worry about e^C so we just call it C?

Comment: @MathMajor That's not a stupid question. $e^C$ is just an unknown constant, and we can express that constant by simplifying it to $C$ to solve for our initial value. The task of solving the IVP "absorbs" that $e$ term since it's not actually a variable- incidentally, that $e$ term shows up in our final solution for C. Furthermore, notice that if we kept it at $e^C$, we'd run into some real trouble solving for our initial value; we'd get $-4 = e^{C-6}$, and would be unable to solve for C.